# Coordinates that follow curvature directions

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

On a 2d surface is it possible to find coordinates that follow the principal curvature directions? I know there are conditions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335987/lines-of-curvature-on-ennepers-surface) for when a curve is a constant curvature line. But how can one find these coordinates numerically given a surface mesh?

Comment: I haven't thought about the numerical issue, but you can prove that there are such *local* coordinates provided there are no umbilic points.